# URL rewrite in apache with dynamic URLs

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm really new at this mod_rewrite stuff and I'm trying to clean up the url from a new application.

I have 2 types of URL in the site. They are always one of the formats below:

```
http://www.site.com/dreams.php?page=view&p=23
http://www.site.com/dreams.php?page=view&p=20
http://www.site.com/dreams.php?page=contact
http://www.site.com/dreams.php?page=contests
```

Now in my main page (dreams.php) I always check to see if $page is set to display the content.
How do I client my url to have:

```
http://www.site.com/view/23
http://www.site.com/view/20
http://www.site.com/contact
http://www.site.com/contests
```

There is one exception to these pages which is when the user searches for content on the vendor page.

```
http://www.site.com/dreams.php?page=vendor_profile&pg=2&cat=&q=c&v_search=
```

I started playing with this but I'm getting some very strange results.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /(.*)/(.*)/$ /dreams.php?page=$1&p=$2
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `.*` is very broad and can consist of a forward slash as well, so to avoid unexpected situations, I would narrow it down, in your case:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(?:/([\d]+)/?)?$ /dreams.php?page=$1&p=$2
```

That would only rewrite:

1. an address containing only lower case characters (a - z)
2. an address starting with only lower case characters, optionally followed by a forward slash and a number and optionally a forward slash at the end.

Note that in your expression, you need to have at least 3 forward slashes to match.

Comment: Thanks. That works... mostly. I had to change my relative paths for css files, etc. I though the implementation of mod-rewrite wouldn't have any impact on the content of the actual page. It was just an alternate way of getting to the page. The pages are up but a lot of the assets are missing.

Comment: @Bruno Yes, relative paths tend to stop working when you use url's like that :-)

Answer (score 0):

It wouldmbe helpful tomknow what strange results youre getting.  That having been said, you should define the base for your rewrite urls. Add RewriteBase / before your first rewrite directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your RewriteRule to this:

```
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/?$ /dreams.php?page=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule /([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /dreams.php?page=$1&p=$2  [L,QSA]
```

This way, query strings get appended so links like this will work: http://www.site.com/vendor_profile?pg=2&cat=&q=c&v_search=